# How to access several ports of a Docker container inside the same container?

Tags: python-3.x, networking, nginx, docker

I am trying to put an application that listens to several ports inside a Docker image.

At the moment, I have one docker image with a Nginx server with the front-end and a Python app: the Nginx runs on the port 27019 and the app runs on 5984.

The index.html file listens to localhost:5984 but it seems like it only listens to it outside the container (on the localhost of my computer).

The only way I can make it work at the moment is by using the -p option twice in the docker run:
    `docker run -p 27019:27019 -p 5984:5984 app-test`.
Doing so, I generate two localhost ports on my computer. If I don't put the `-p 5984:5984` it doesn't work.
I plan on using more ports for the application, so I'd like to avoid adding -p xxx:xxx for each new port.

How can I make an application inside the container (in this case the index.html at 27019) listens to another port inside the same container, without having to publish both of them? Can it be generalized to more than two ports? The final objective would be to have a complete application running on a single port on a server/computer, while listening to several ports inside Docker container(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose two virtual hosts on the same outgoing port then you need a proxy like for example https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy .

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good thing to put a lot of applications into one container, normally you should split that with one container per app, it's the way it should be used.

But if you absolutly want to use many apps into one container you can use proxy or write a dockerfile that will open your ports itself.

Comment: Yes that's probably what I´m gonna do, but won't it use several ports of the server/localhost?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you want to access to your applications by one port on your host and map it to one port to your container ? If it's what you want you do you'll have many problems...
You can use proxy to access to your app by different ports mapped to only one port of your container but in any case you'll have to use many `-p` flags...
I really advise you to put one app per container.. If you want to use multiple applications in one virtualized machine use a classic VM on VirtualBox or VMWare if you have it...